# I only have one AdControl, but I need to put two AdUnitId

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a uwp app, and I finished it and was preparing to submit my app in the store, through the dev center. My application has `AdControl` advertising, which is presented in the desktop version (Windows 10) and the mobile version (Windows 10 Mobile) through `VisualStateManager`

My `AdControl`: (example)

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab"
         AdUnitId="test"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="250"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="300"/>
```

In the Desktop version I have:

```
<Setter Target="Ad.Height" Value="90"/>
<Setter Target="Ad.Width" Value="728"/>
```

In the Mobile version I have:

```
<Setter Target="Ad.Height" Value="50"/>
<Setter Target="Ad.Width" Value="320"/>
```

That is, the size of the banner adapts to the different screen sizes.

In Dev Center, I have to generate 2 AdUnitId, one for PC/tablet and other to mobile.

How do I do that?

I just have an `AdControl`, which allows me to put just one ID

Answer (score 1):

In the Setter for mobile, try

```
<Setter Target="Ad.AdUnitId" Value="<Mobile Ad ID>"/>
```

and for desktop

```
<Setter Target="Ad.AdUnitId" Value="<Desktop Ad ID>"/>
```